# Testing javascript output in XSL

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am attempting to bring the current url into my xsl.  The only way I found to do this was using javascript.  The problem is the output I'm getting from javascript isn't what I was expecting.

document.location: http://mydomainname/PressRoom/Pages/PressReleases.aspx?start=1

```
        <xsl:variable name="start">
                <![CDATA[
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    urlString = new String(document.location);
                    nwls = urlString.split('start=');
                    document.write(nwls[1]);                    
                </script>
                ]]>
        </xsl:variable> 
        start=<xsl:value-of select="$start" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

        <xsl:if test="$start = '1'">
          start variable contains 1
        </xsl:if>
```

output:  start= 1

The test for $start = 1 is not true

If I check that $start contains 'script type='  that test is true

How can I test the variable $start with disable output escaping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
            <![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
                urlString = new String(document.location);
                nwls = urlString.split('start=');
                document.write(nwls[1]);                    
            </script>
            ]]>
```

you want

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <![CDATA[
                urlString = new String(document.location);
                nwls = urlString.split('start=');
                document.write(nwls[1]);                    
            ]]>
            </script>
```

The former is a text block containing the text `"<script...>"` and the latter is a `<script>` element containing the text inside the CDATA section.

But I think you're confused about what happens when.  The XSL engine runs and completes before scripts are run.  So you can't test whether `start` is 1 inside, because the JavaScript environment hasn't been set up yet.

Also be aware that some older versions of Firefox closed the document before applying XSL, which means that `document.write`, which starts a new document if the existing one has been closed, will blow away the XSL generated content on those browsers.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I appreciate the answer. What I'm trying to accomplish is to bring the current url into XSLT.  Would you know of anyway to do this besides Javascript?